# Can I buy an Epic Breeding Island for cash?

Tags: dragonvale

Can an **Epic Breeding Island** be purchased for gold at any time of the game?

Comment: If you have real gold and convert it to cash to buy the gems, then yes.  Otherwise, no.

Answer (score 2):

From [this](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Epic_Breeding_Island) website.

The Epic Breeding Island is **unlocked at Level 13**. The cost for this is **125 Gems**. Therefore, it looks like you can't buy it with gold, and you can't buy it at any time of the game unless you are level 13 or higher.